# Java: How to get data from ArrayList<Data Type>

Tags: arraylist, methods, call

I'm trying to make an app that manages contacts. I'm having difficulty getting the data within those contacts.

### This is my ContactsManager class

public class ContactsManager {

```
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

public void createContact(String name, String phoneNumber){
    Contact contact = new Contact(name, phoneNumber);
    contacts.add(contact);
}
```

}

### And This is my Contact class

public class Contact {

```
private String name, phoneNumber;

public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber){
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getNumber(){
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

}

How would I go about getting the Names and Numbers that I pass into the ArrayList? Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @agelakute, I just posted an answer of how to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add the entry in the list, you only need to get by position, like:

```
Contact firstContact = contacts.get(0);
firstContact.getName();
firstContact.getNumber();
```

Or for all contacts:

```
contacts.forEach(contact -> {
    System.out.println(contact.getName());
    System.out.println(contact.getNumber());
});
```